# extending the AspNetUsers with profiles and roles etc - VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, authorize-attribute

I need a way of having:

- A super admin user that can administrate all users.
- A Register / Log in form that allows users to register with a username and password and log in using that too
- Once signed up, a way of adding further details to their profile.

I know that MVC 4.0 - 5.0 has [AuthorizeAttribute] and I want to make use of Microsoft's security rather than hash my way with some crappy User table that's easy to hack at and makes other developers want to cry.

So I can see there is a database table called **AspNetUsers** and in that table is an Id column. So I assume that I allow a user to register using the in-built register form... then when signed in they can use my own EF UserProfile class structure to fill in details about themselves:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; } // Will link the profile to the user created by Microsofts own authentication do-raggy
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Does this all sound about right  or am I missing out on some tricks?

**How do I go about adding roles to users?** It's all new to me (in terms of using this framework). So let's say, I need to add myself as superadmin, I need a superadmin role.

Then I need to make it so any person can register to the application as a member role...

Finally as a super admin, I need to be able to grant individuals who have registered as ProjectAdministrators... then I can make use of the attribute tag [Authorize(role="ProjectAdministrators")]

I understand the logistics here but an example of adding roles to users and linking profiles to users would be spot on for me!

---

What if It was an important thing to have users sign up with an email address as well as just username and password. Do I simply add columns to the AspNetUsers database table?.. where do I define the new property for the AspNetUsers model?

Comment: There are ways to implement this via providers.  You are already using the default MembershipProvider, why not have a look at the profile provider? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.ASPX  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I took a long dump on my application and added a UserProfile table, have got it all working.. then I came back to your link and found an even better link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx and now am killing myself that I wasted a whole day thinking continuing the above would help me :) Thanks bud. @Ps2goat Please can you add yours as an answer but also include my link as it was the ultimate guide :) ... Should help others then!

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to implement this via providers.

You are already using the default MembershipProvider, why not have a look at the profile provider? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k.ASPX msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taab950e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Here's a link that helped @JamesT more than the profile provider's technical 'description' (lack of detail from MS):  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx